# HTMLElement.focus() not working inside HTMLElement.onpointerdown

Tags: javascript, html

lets say i have this `html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="application/javascript" src="./jsfile.js" defer></script>
   </head>   
   <body>
       <p>some text</p>
       <input type="text">
   <body>
</html>
```

and this `javascript` file called `jsfile.js`

```
let p=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
let input=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
p.onpointerdown=()=>{
   input[0].focus();
};
```

what i am trying to do here is when the `pointerdown` event is called on the `<p>` element, the input element get focused.
i tried with `mouseclick` event and it worked but i cant get it to work on the `pointerdown` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You are not defining **element** variable at all
2. You are getting a list of elements (by using document.getElementsByTagName). In that case you will get in a **p** variable a collection of items, and you cannot use like .focus and other things on a collection (although its possible in jquery)

Rather you should use something like this:

```
// This will give you a single element
const p = document.querySelector("p");
// Same thing here
let input=document.querySelector("input");

p.onpointerdown = (e) => {
   // This part is necessary here to avoid default begaviour
   // Mose browsers would fire mousedown event if this event is not canceled, therefore it will affect your focus 
   e.preventDefault(); 

   input.focus();

};
```

Comment: yep just fixed the issues, didnt notice the problems this was more of an example ,
the .preventDefault() fixed the problme tho